# making object face towards mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, rotation

I am a beginner in javascript.
i am trying to make a very basic 2d top down shooter game in which i want to rotate my player towrds the mouse cursor.
i have seen other questions about this but none are working for me.
please tell a way to do this(i have never made this kind of game before.)
i have attached my code snippet  which i have to rotate towards the mouse.(the "player1 variable")
disclaimer: i am a beginner(thought i would mention)

```
//variables
var player1;
var gun1;
var gun2;


function preload(){

}

function setup(){
    //creating sprites
    player1 = createSprite(200,200,30,30)
    gun = createSprite(player1.x,player1.y-20,5,30)
    gun.shapeColor = "black"
}

function draw(){
  canvas = createCanvas(displayWidth-20, displayHeight-120);
   background("#32CD32");
   gun.x = player1.x;
   gun.y = player1.y-15;
   // functions to move
   //up
  if(keyDown("up")){
    player1.y = player1.y - 5;
  }
  //down
  if(keyDown("down")){
    player1.y = player1.y + 5;
  }
  //right
  if(keyDown("right")){
    player1.x = player1.x + 5;
  }
  //left
  if(keyDown("left")){
    player1.x = player1.x - 5;
  }

 

drawSprites();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would add a [mousemove event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event) to get the coordinates of the mouse. From the given documentation:

```js
myPics.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    x = e.offsetX;
    y = e.offsetY;
});
```

Then, you need to know the current player position of course, but that is known to you in the player variable already.

You can now get the difference in x and y as you both know the mouse, and the player's position, which gives you a triangle. You can calculate the triangles angles using [pythagoras theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) and then rotate the player according to the angle you calculated (or probably have the angle, as you want the players center to be in the center of the angle).

You should really try to solve it yourself from there, as you will only improve your coding skills by trial and error and reading documentations and trying to understand things yourself. However, I hope I could show you a general direction to go for.

Comment: thanks! just to confirm, i need to find the difference in the x and y values of player and mouse(if players x pos is 50 and mouses x pos is 70 it will be 20 ) and use them to find the value of the hypotenuse using the pythagoras theorem and then find the angle of it, right?

Comment: You probably don't even need the hypothenus and I cant tell from my head which is which method to calculate which angle, you will have to look into some maths to find out, sorry ;) But it will work for soure if you do your math correct. Youtube will help!